# pass parameter from $.post() callback to outer variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

basically i want to hold a parameter that retrieve value from $.post() call like this:

```
init = function(){          
var lastpage = getLastPage();
}

        function getLastPage(){
            $.post("getInfo.php",{ 
                last: "yes"
            },
            function(data){
                setLast(data.last);
            },'json');

            return function setLast(data){
                return data;
            }
        }
```

so when reach at last post (last page) i should check with lastpage variable that has a value returned from getLastPage() function.

I'm pretty blur with javascript pointer and all. Please help guys.

update (20/4/2010):

I've done the other way around, like this:

```
init = function(){            
  getLastPage();
  if((page+1) == $("#lastpage").val()){
     alert("this is last post");
  }else{
     page++;
     //get info and display to the page here
  }
}
     function getLastPage(){
        $.post("getInfo.php",{ 
            last: "yes"
        },
        function(data){
            $("#lastpage").val(data.last);
        },'json');
    }
```

first run the function to temporarily store the value in hidden input tag (lastpage) and then grab the value again to check it whenever i click forward button.

if you all have more appropriate way please tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your code around like this:

```
$.post("getInfo.php",{ last: "yes" },
  function(data){ 
    functionToRunAfterYouHaveDataSometimeLater(data.last); 
  }
,'json');
```

The problem with your overall approach is that with AJAX, you're dealing with an asynchronous operation.  This means that the `function(data) { }` portion doesn't run then, it runs *later*, so your `return` doesn't actually return anything, it'll be `undefined`.

Instead of this approach, you need to call `$.post()` then call whatever function relies on this data to continue as part of `$.post()`'s callback.  After doing that your code order looks like this:

- `$.post()` executes, firing off a request to the server
- The rest of your code after `$.post()` runs
- **Later** when the response comes from the server and you have data, your callback executes
- Now continue to do what you need with that data